# Who are the two ladies in Major Kusanagi's apartment?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac

In episode 5 when Major Kusanagi is reviewing the original Laughing Man incident footage in her own apartment, two girls can be seen with her. One bringing over a cocktail and then both unknown girls sleeping near Matoko on the bed.

One appears to be dressed a a maid, and for giving Major her drink I assume she's her personal maid bot.

[image] [image]

The other girl's outfit I can't identify. She has dark hair. The maid has brighter colored hair.

[image]

Once again in episode 20 we see the bright-haired girl talking to Major while she's preparing to switch bodies. Apparently the body switching procedure requires for a witness. We also know that cloned people cannot inherit real estate. I'm not sure if these factors are connected, but something tells me a bot wouldn't be a legible witness for body switching. Possibly the girls are people, not androids.

[image]

Who are these two girls? Are they people or are they androids? What are their names? What are their responsibilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the Major's friends/friends-with-benefits. (She actually does have a life outside work.) The one with darker hair is named Ran; the one with lighter hair is Kurutan. She isn't a maid bot, she's just wearing a frilly dress and getting Motoko drinks, well, *'cause*... (By the way, I think it's actually Kurutan's apartment -- the Major was borrowing her virtual reality equipment to review the case.)

Kurutan is actually also featured in episode 8: She works as a nurse, and the organ trafficking case involves two of her patients. She calls in the Major and Section 9 after the police investigation founders.

I haven't read the manga, but I understand that it features more of Motoko's relationships. Apparently she had a boyfriend (who made one cameo in *SAC*), and she had a virtual threesome with Kurutan and Ran, as opposed to their more implied relationship here.

I don't know more about them. Still, with their names, you should be able to find some more on Google.

(References: [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/GhostInTheShellStandAloneComplex), [Wikia](https://ghostintheshell.wikia.com/wiki/Kurutan), and the credits.)